# Adding a custom ant task to custom_rules.xml in my Android project

Tags: android, ant, build

I want to add a task to the Ant script for my Android project in order to generate Javadocs from the source code. To do so, I have modified the `custom_rules.xml` file as

```
<project name="bbct-android-common-tests-custom-rules" default="help">
    <property name="javadoc.dir" value=""/>
    <task name="javadoc" description="Generate Javadocs">
        <javadoc sourcedir="${src.dir}" destdir="${javadoc.dir}"/>
    </task>
</project>
```

And added the following line to `ant.properties`:

```
javadoc.dir=javadoc
```

Now when I run `ant javadoc`, I get the following error message:

> $ ant javadoc
>   Buildfile: e:\devel\src\java\bbct\android\common\test\build.xml
>
> BUILD FAILED
>   e:\devel\src\java\bbct\android\common\test\build.xml:69: The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   e:\devel\src\java\bbct\android\common\test\custom_rules.xml:22: Problem: failed to create task or type task
>   Cause: The name is undefined.
>   Action: Check the spelling.
>   Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
>   Action: Check that any / declarations have taken place.
>
> Total time: 0 seconds

I also replaced my property values in the `<javadoc>` task and still get the same error.

Also, my google search has been in vain. I have found several articles about building Javadocs from Eclipse and writing custom Ant scripts in general, just nothing about simply adding a task to the default script. Does anyone know where I can look to figure out what I need to do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be

```
<target name="javadoc" description="Generate Javadocs">
        <javadoc sourcedir="${src.dir}" destdir="${javadoc.dir}"/>
</target>
```

Notice the use of `target` and not `task`